# How to Copy Apache DS Configuration and Data (from one apacheds to another)

Tags: apache-ds

I have one Apache DS running on win server 2008 and another on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS and I need to copy whole configuration and data from the win one to the ubuntu one. I tried export, but when I try to import in ubuntu apacheds i get 'Import LDIF' has encountered a problem. Error while importing LDIF - [LDAP: error code 32 - NO_SUCH_OBJECT... type of errors. I also tried importing objects separately, and also tried to create partitions manually (according to original win apacheds partitions) and then start the import, but I still got errors. Any Ideas how can I do it?  Many Thanks.